# Distribution of $\lceil X \rceil - X$ where $X$ has an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with exponential distribution of parameter $\lambda > 0$. That is, $X$ has density $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \mathcal{1}_{\mathbb{[0,\infty [}}$.

The question is :

> What is the distribution of $Y = \lceil X \rceil - X$ where $\lceil . \rceil$ is the ceiling function ?

I wonder if the following calculation is true  :

Since $0 \leq Y < 1$, then $P(Y < 0) = 0$ and $P(Y < 1) = 1$

For $0 < a < 1$, 
$$\begin{align}
P(Y < a) &= P(\cup _{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \{ k \leq X < k+a \}) \\ &= \sum _{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \int _k ^{k+a} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \mathcal{1}_{\mathbb{[0,\infty [}} dx \\ &= \sum _{k \in \mathbb{N}} \int _k ^{k+a} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx \\ &= \sum _{k \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda e^{-\lambda k} \int _0 ^{a} e^{-\lambda x}  dx \\ &= \sum _{k \in \mathbb{N}} e^{-\lambda k} (1 - e^{-\lambda a}) \\ &= \frac{1- e^{-\lambda a}}{1 - e^{-\lambda}} 
\end{align} $$
So for $0 < a,b < 1$, $P(a < Y < b) = \frac{e^{-\lambda a} - e^{-\lambda b}}{1 - e^{-\lambda}}$

Does anyone have a remark about this calculation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation is correct. The result can be derived more easily by noting that the density in each interval is just a scaled version of the density in the first interval, so you get the right density by normalising the density restricted to the first interval.